# Different printing results in Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, printer, ubuntu-11.04

I have an Epson D78 stylus and I use it mainly on Windows 7 64-bit. I downloaded the driver from the Epson support site for my Windows 7 64 bit version and it's up to date.

I also installed Ubuntu on my computer, a 32bit version where the driver was installed automatically, so I didn't do anything.

Using Windows 7 to print I often have a lot of problems (80% of times), e.g. a lot of ink lost and the paper often gets dirty. When I use my Ubuntu version to print, everything is perfect, not even a line out of place, not a dirty pixel.

I also noticed that the printing speed is different from one OS to another, being slower on Ubuntu.

Why is that happening? Shouldn't be better on Windows, as the driver was actually designed to be used on Windows?

Comment: Have you tried to use the 32-but windows driver?

Comment: shouldn't cause problems installing a 32bit driver on a 64 architecture?

Comment: I've never had any issues installing 32-bit printer drivers. In fact, my HP printer driver for my home printer is 32 bit and works great.

Comment: Ok, I understand but it seems like a nonsense thing to do. Epson provides a windows 7 64 bit driver for my printer, why use a 32 bit? What should change from a 32 bit version to a 64 one surely it's not the printing speed or the quality. But I'll try to unistall my current driver and try the 32 bit one to see if is there any difference.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it may be worth a try, which is why I posted the suggestion as a comment instead of an answer.